# Unable to start mongod service getting connection error message

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run start mongo from the folder with command

```
./mongod --dbpath /opt/mangodb_install/data/db/ --logpath /opt/mangodb_install/mongod.log --port 27018 --fork
```

but i m getting an error

> [root@staging bin]# ./mongo MongoDB shell version v3.4.2-rc0
>   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 2017-12-05T12:30:30.978+0530
>   W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking
>   socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
>   2017-12-05T12:30:30.979+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't
>   connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13 @(connect):1:6 exception:
>   connect failed

Answer (score 0):

You changed port from the standard (`27017`) into `27018`. So you must to define the port for `mongo`.

Try this:

```
mongo --port 27018
```